# Why is my cube failing to draw properly in LWJGL/OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I believe it has something to do with draw order, but I've just given up at this point.
Basically, the Quads are drawing, but they're not in the right order, and backface culling is enabled but doesn't help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Main {
public Main() {
    this.start();
}
private void start() {  
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640,640));
        Display.setTitle("FPSTest");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(-5, 5, -5, 5, -1, 5);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    int x=0;
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        Display.sync(60);
        //poll for keypresses first, default key is 'forward'
        //if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_NUMPAD8));



        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE|GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        GL11.glRotatef(x++, 1, 1, 1);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);          // Set The Color To Green
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f);          // Set The Color To Orange
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);          // Set The Color To Red
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);          // Set The Color To Yellow
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);          // Set The Color To Blue
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);          // Set The Color To Violet
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // Top Right Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // Top Left Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new Main();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE|GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

You can't do this. You have to give each glEnable as a separate command. Try this instead and see if it helps you.

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Also use `glGetError`!